# Force installation of doc packages

Tags: debian, aptitude, documentation

I often find myself missing documentation when I happen to be offline. For this reason, I would like to force `aptitude` to install the corresponding doc packages whenever I install a package. Is there a way of doing that more elegant than putting an alias that goes through arguments and add the `*-doc` that exist before forwarding the arguments to `aptitude`?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Can you provide an illustration?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I'm not sure but he must mean the development literature for related libraries, for instance [this](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/gimp/filelist) vs. [that](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libgimp2.0-doc)?

Comment: @illuminÉ Yes, possibly. But in any case, I don't think this can be automated as requested. For one thin, packages, even in Debian, are not named so consistently. You have to approach this on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following shell snippet installs all `FOO-doc` packages such that `FOO` is already installed:

```
apt-get install $(comm -12 <(dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2 == "install" {print $1 "-doc"}')
                           <(apt-cache pkgnames | sort) )
```

To make this a bit cleaner by omitting already-installed `-doc` packages:

```
installed_packages=$(dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2 == "install" {print $1}')
uninstalled_doc_packages=$(comm -13 <(printf '%s\n' $installed_packages)
                                    <(printf '%s-doc\n' $installed_packages))
missing_doc_packages=$(apt-cache pkgnames | sort |
                       comm -12 - <(printf '%s\n' $uninstalled_doc_packages))
apt-get install $missing_doc_packages
```

I don't think there's a handy way to run this automatically after a package installation¹ or to automatically mark the `-doc` packages to be installed.

¹  <sub>You can set a dpkg or apt hook, but it'll run after package removals, upgrades, etc., not just after installing packages.</sub>